# tSQLt - A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate 'Private'

Tags: .net, message, private, tsqlt

I'm trying to call a test procedure using tSQLt. The test succeeds, but I however get the following error message:

A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate 'Private'

The database is already set to TRUSTWORTHY ON and CLR is enabled (sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1;)

Any idea to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

```
EXEC tSQLt.NewTestClass 'MyTestClass';
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [MyTestClass].[test 1]
AS
BEGIN
    EXEC tSQLt.AssertEquals 1, 1;
END
GO

EXEC tSQLt.Run 'MyTestClass.[test 1]'
GO
```

Comment: Try it without the space in the procedure name

Comment: calling an another procedure without spaces in the name causes the same error

Comment: Have you executed a RECONFIGURE command on the database?

Comment: yes, RECONFIGURE was already executed

Comment: Not sure - try running the tsqlt.class.sql again - it should rebuild all the objects

Comment: ran tsql.class.sql again, but doesn't help either...

Comment: Suggest run tSQLt.Uninstall then restart sql server then tsql.class.sql again

Comment: Have you tried running the samples supplied in the download?

Comment: @sinan.petrus - did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue.